# GUI programming errors in CMD after compile

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, textpad

I'm trying to make a simple game which i made array of 9 buttons and for loops to display them and add then to ContentPane.

I'm trying to add images to the buttons in the for loops and I cannot get it to work./ any help?

```
    String[] images = {"rainbow.jpg", "leprechaun.jpg", "potofgold.jpg"}; // IMAGES

    // --- ICONS ---
    Icon Icon1 = new ImageIcon("rainbow.jpg");
    Icon Icon2 = new ImageIcon("leprechaun.jpg");
    Icon Iconwin = new ImageIcon("potofgold2.jpg");
    Icon blank = new ImageIcon("blank.jpg");

    //creates array of buttons called tiles
    JButton[] tile = new JButton[9];
```

They are the arrays and Icons.

```
for(int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++)
        {
            contentPane.add(tile[i]);
            tile[i].setIcon(images[1]);
            tile[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
```

I'm trying to make it random image to the buttons. selects randomly I cannot get it to work I get error on tile[i].setIcon(images[1])

even when trying to just place it the 2nd image it give sme error

method setIcon in class AbstractButton cannot be applied to given types;

```
            tile[i].setIcon(images[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`setIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIcon(javax.swing.Icon)) uses an `Icon` as its argument rather than a `String`

```
tile[i].setIcon(icon1);
```

Adding the buttons directly would be simpler

```
getContentPane().add(new ImageIcon(images[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks is there anyway of adding the images using from images[]? I need to add a random image to the buttons , should select 1 random image out of them 3.

Comment: It would be simpler but the assignment wants to be images randomized and this way is the easiest to achieve that. I tried getContentPane().add(new ImageIcon(images[i]);

getting no suitable constructor found for ImageIcon(icon)

Comment: To add a random image use the `Random` class to select a `String` from `images` to pass into the `ImageIcon` constructor

Comment: If i just try  to tile[i].setIcon(imageIcons[i]);

I get errors in cmd after i run it.

java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception: 3
 
   at assignmentbk.<init><assignmentbk.java:67>
   at assignmentbk.main<assignmentbk.java:81

Comment: `tile` is an array of length `9` whereas `images` is only `3` in length

Comment: I see that I got it to atleast print out the images onto the buttons but I cannot get them to print out randomly.. on all of the buttons. it just prints on 3 buttons and they are in order.. im using
if(e.getSource()==tile[i])
    {
     tile[i].setIcon(imageIcons[i]);  // sets IMAGES to buttons

    }